# Get domain name for service in Angular2

Tags: angular

I need to make request to same server, REST API on another port.

How can I do this without hardcoding full name in service URLs?

Answer (score 87, accepted):

There's no need for an angular2-specific solution. You can use the [`window.location.hostname`](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp) to get the current hostname.

Note, however, if you don't want to use global variables like the `window`-object directly, you can provide your own `Window` object, which then can be injected.

See this full working [Stackblitz Angular sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-window-hostname) for details.

### Updated Answer for Angular 6+

As others have stated, the original answer does not work anymore. For Angular 6+, you need to provide an [Injection Token](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken), so that the `window`-object can be resolved in the [AOT](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler)-build too.
Otherwise you will get the error "Can't resolve all parameters".

I recommend creating a `WINDOW_PROVIDERS` array in a separate file like this:

```js
import { InjectionToken, FactoryProvider } from '@angular/core';

export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken<Window>('window');

const windowProvider: FactoryProvider = {
  provide: WINDOW,
  useFactory: () => window
};

export const WINDOW_PROVIDERS = [
    windowProvider
]
```

The `WINDOW_PROVIDERS` constant can be added to the `providers` array in the `AppModule` like this:

```js
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [
    WINDOW_PROVIDERS, // <- add WINDOW_PROVIDERS here
    SampleService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

In the `SampleService`, the `window` object can be injected by using the defined [Injection Token](https://angular.io/api/core/InjectionToken) like this:

```js
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { WINDOW } from '../window.provider';

@Injectable()
export class SampleService {

    constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) private window: Window) {
    }

    getHostname() : string {
        return this.window.location.hostname;
    }
}
```

### Original Answer for Angular 2

Therefore you need to set the provider for the `Window`-object when bootstrapping your application.

```js
import {provide} from 'angular2/core';
bootstrap(..., [provide(Window, {useValue: window})]);
```

After that you can use the window object and access the hostname like this:

```js
constructor(private window: Window) {
   var hostname = this.window.location.hostname;
}
```

Comment: What are the advantages of using your own Window object vs using a global constant? Thanks

Comment: This will not work on Angular 6 anymore. You will get an error with `Can't resolve all parameters`. To make this work you have to declare an injection token and then use it in the constructor. I will add an answer to make this more explicit.

Comment: what about angular universal? this is still working with the window_providers?

Comment: This will fail for 'ng build --prod=true'. To fix this, the useFactory needs to be a normal function.

Comment: @StefHeyenrath I've tested the prod build and it works for me. I've also added a  [Stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-window-hostname) which also works in the prod build.

Comment: @M.E. I still get this error: "ERROR in src\app\app.module.ts(32,3): Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function expressions are not supported in decorators in 'WindowProvider'
    'WindowProvider' references 'WindowProvider'
      'WindowProvider' references 'WindowProvider'
        'WindowProvider' contains the error at src\app\common\utils\window.provider.ts(9,17)
          Consider changing the function expression into an exported function."

I'll try to create a sample project on github.

Comment: DI just to get the window object...talk about overcomplication. lol

Comment: @bubble (and others)  The answer to why you would do this through injection is:  **Unit Testing**.  If, for example, you want to unit test that your method correctly constructs a URI from the location (e.g. origin + pathname + new path) then opens a new window to that path... you need to provide a fake:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/40320802/5753629

Answer (score 41):

Another option is to use DOCUMENT from @angular/platform-browser.

```
import {DOCUMENT} from '@angular/platform-browser';

constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document) {
    let url = document.location.protocol +'//'+ document.location.hostname + ':my_port' );
}
```

Comment: Isn´t this the same as using `document.origin` ?

Comment: `DOCUMENT` does not seem to be a [documented](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser) part of `@angular/platform-browser`.

Comment: Error: “@angular/platform-browser/platform-browser” has no exported member 'DOCUMENT'

Comment: [`DOCUMENT`](https://angular.io/api/common/DOCUMENT) is available in `@angular/common`

Comment: or you could just use `document.location.origin`

Comment: this should be the accepted answer as this is both work for Angular CSR and SSR.

Answer (score 11):

Angular 2 **latest** working solution:

app.module.ts

```
providers: [
    {provide: Window, useValue: window},
    ...
]
```

youclass.ts

```
constructor(
    @Inject(Window) private _window: Window
) {
    this._baseUrl = `http://${this._window.location.hostname}:3333`;
};
```

Comment: this worked for me.  the Location service from in @angular/common was useless

Answer (score 11):

You can use `window`, as others have stated, and to make it injectable, from ng6 and forward, you need an injection token.

Declare the token like this:

```js
export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken('window',
    { providedIn: 'root', factory: () => window }
);
```

Then use it in the class constructor:

```js
class Foo {
  constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) private window: Window) { }
}
```

As `Window` is an interface in TypeScript, if you don't do the injection like that, when you build the project for production you will get an error: `Can't resolve all parameters for <ClassName>`.
And later another one: `ERROR in : Error: Internal error: unknown identifier undefined`.

To understand injection better, read the angular docs for DI:
https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection

Comment: You can also get the window object with `document.defaultView`

Answer (score 8):

I'm using plain javascript and [URL native api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) for URL parsing:

```
declare var window: any; // Needed on Angular 8+
const parsedUrl = new URL(window.location.href);
const baseUrl = parsedUrl.origin;
console.log(baseUrl); // this will print http://example.com or http://localhost:4200
```

Comment: This is the cleanest and most lightweight answer to the problem. Much appreciated.

Comment: This isn't working on Angular 8 however if you use ````declare var window: any;```` then it's working

Answer (score 4):

I achieved it with following code in my `app.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: any) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.domain = this.document.location.hostname;
        console.log(this.domain);
    }
}
```

This should print the domain name in your console.

Comment: This worked for me, however my linter showed a deprecated warning and advised this instead:
`import {DOCUMENT} from "@angular/common";`

Answer (score 4):

I test this on Angular 7 and it worked correctly

```
declare var window: any;

console.log (window.location.host); //result lrlucas.github.io > domain github pages
```

with window.location.host I get the full domain

Note: Declare the window variable before `@Component`

Comment: Have you tried your code with `'ng build --prod=true`?

Comment: Yes @James Poulose, compile a project of angular with
`ng build --prod=true` and run a server with this command `http-server -o -p 8081` and the result of in the console was `127.0.0.1:8081`

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using `window.location` as others have kindly stated.

*However*, you can also do this by importing Angular's common 'Location' library and using it in an injectable like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Location }   from '@angular/common';
const otherPort = 8000;

@Injectable()
export class ServiceOrComponentName {
  constructor(location: Location) {
    this.baseUrl = location._platformStrategy._platformLocation._location.protocol +
      '//' + location._platformStrategy._platformLocation._location.hostname +
      ':' + otherPort;
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is best practice, as you rely on private attributes, that can change in the future.

Comment: I agree. However it is frustrating having the data right there and not being able to properly access it.

Comment: _platformStrategy not available in angular 14.

Answer (score 2):

Just inject Document.  Angular has a default implementation for Document.  Document has a property called defaultView that has all the goodies like window.

```
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';
import { Inject, Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HostnameService
{

  constructor(
    @Inject(DOCUMENT) private document: Document
  ) { }

  getHostname(): string
  {
    // Remember to use this.document as unscoped document also exists but is not mockable.
    return this.document.defaultView.window.location.hostname;

    // Or use the location on document.
    return this.document.location.hostname;

  }
}
```

There is no setup required elsewhere.