# Unit Testing/mocking Window properties in Angular2 (TypeScript)

Tags: unit-testing, typescript, angular, phantomjs, karma-jasmine

I'm building some unit tests for a service in Angular2.

Within my Service I have the following code:

`var hash: string;
 hash = this.window.location.hash;`

However when I run a test which contains this code, it will fail.

It'd be great to utilise all the features of Window, but as I'm using PhantomJs, I don't think this is possible (I have also tried Chrome which yields the same results).

In AngularJs, I would have resorted to mocking $Window (or at least the properties in question), but as there is not a lot of documentation for Angular2 unit testing I'm not sure how to do this.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It seems to be [quite straghtforward](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34177221/angular2-how-to-inject-window-into-an-angular2-service). Probably an XY problem, because the router already [has the hash abstracted](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/03627aa84d90f7f1d8d62f160997b783fdf9eaa4/modules/angular2/src/router/location/hash_location_strategy.ts#L64), the abstraction goes up to [DOM location](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/platform/browser/BrowserDomAdapter-class.html#!#getLocation).

Answer (score 35):

In Angular 2 you can use the `@Inject()` function to inject the window object by naming it using a string token, like this

```
  constructor( @Inject('Window') private window: Window) { }
```

In the `@NgModule` you must then provide it using the same string:

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [ ... ],
    imports: [ ... ],
    providers: [ { provide: 'Window', useValue: window } ],
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Then you can also mock it using the token string

```
beforeEach(() => {
  let windowMock: Window = <any>{ };
  TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    providers: [
      ApiUriService,
      { provide: 'Window', useFactory: (() => { return windowMock; }) }
    ]
  });
```

This worked in Angular 2.1.1, the latest as of 2016-10-28.

Does not work with Angular 4.0.0 AOT.
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/15640

Comment: This works for testing but not in AoT compilation (compiles but with a warning and the app crashes in the browser)

Comment: Tried this with an AoT build (along with typing `window` as `any` inside the constructor to work around a different bug), but my production build crashed when I tried to access a custom property on `window` that I'm setting in another file. I followed the solution here instead, and it worked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37176929/1683187

Comment: This is the correct answer for changing the windowMock object dynamically in each test when needed

Comment: it works for me: Angular 10

Answer (score 9):

As @estus mentioned in the comment, you'd be better getting the hash from the Router. But to answer your question directly, you need to inject window into the place you're using it, so that during testing you can mock it.

First, register window with the angular2 provider - probably somewhere global if you use this all over the place:

```
import { provide } from '@angular/core';
provide(Window, { useValue: window });
```

This tells angular when the dependency injection asks for the type `Window`, it should return the global `window`.

Now, in the place you're using it, you inject this into your class instead of using the global directly:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({ ... })
export default class MyCoolComponent {
    constructor (
        window: Window
    ) {}

    public myCoolFunction () {
        let hash: string;
        hash = this.window.location.hash;
    }
}
```

Now you're ready to mock that value in your test.

```
import {
    beforeEach,
    beforeEachProviders,
    describe,
    expect,
    it,
    inject,
    injectAsync
} from 'angular2/testing';

let myMockWindow: Window;
beforeEachProviders(() => [
    //Probably mock your thing a bit better than this..
    myMockWindow = <any> { location: <any> { hash: 'WAOW-MOCK-HASH' }};
    provide(Window, {useValue: myMockWindow})
]);

it('should do the things', () => {
    let mockHash = myMockWindow.location.hash;
    //...
});
```

Comment: You can also just inject `constructor(window:Window)` and provide it like `provide(Window, {useValue: window})` or `provide(Window, {useClass: MyWindowMock})`. No need to use a string key if there is a type available.

Comment: [provide removed in RC6](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes) from core, change it to `providers: [
    {provide: Window, useValue: window},
  ]`

Comment: This is a lifesaver.  Enabled me to mock the tests I needed without the page redirecting.  Worked in Angular 11

Comment: TypeError: Cannot set properties of undefined (setting 'href') - when trying this.window.location.href = 'abc'

Answer (score 5):

After RC4 method `provide()` its depracated, so the way to handle this after RC4 is:

```
  let myMockWindow: Window;

  beforeEach(() => {
    myMockWindow = <any> { location: <any> {hash: 'WAOW-MOCK-HASH'}};
    addProviders([SomeService, {provide: Window, useValue: myMockWindow}]);
  });
```

It take me a while to figure it out, how it works.

Comment: That syntax is deprecated in the release version of Angular2

Answer (score 3):

Injection tokens with built-in factories seem like the way to go.

I'm using these for any browser global like window, document, localStorage, console, etc.

core/providers/window.provider.ts

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export const WINDOW = new InjectionToken<Window>(
    'Window',
    {
        providedIn: 'root',
        factory(): Window {
            return window;
        }
    }
);
```

Injection:

```
constructor(@Inject(WINDOW) private window: Window)
```

Unit Tests:

```
const mockWindow = {
  setTimeout: jest.fn(),
  clearTImeout: jest.fn()
};

TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  providers: [
    {
      provide: WINDOW,
      useValue: mockWindow
    }
  ]
});
```

Comment: This was a pretty conclusive answer for me. I put my injection token in to my app.module file and then just imported/injected it in to all components that needed to set the location href.

Answer (score 0):

I really don't get why nobody provided the easiest solution which is the **recommended way by the Angular-Team to test a service** as you can see [here](https://angular.io/guide/testing-services). You even don't have to deal with the TestBed stuff at all in most of the cases.

Futhermore, you can use this approach for components and directives as well. In that case, you won't create a component-instance but a class-instance. This means, you don't have to deal with the child-components used within the components template as well.

Assuming you are able to inject Window into your constructor

```
constructor(@Inject(WINDOW_TOKEN) private _window: Window) {}
```

Just do the following in your .spec file:

```
describe('YourService', () => {
  let service: YourService;
  
  beforeEach(() => {
    service = new YourService(
      {
        location: {hash: 'YourHash'} as any,
        ...
      } as any,
      ...
    );
  });
}
```

I don't care about other properties, therefore I usually add a type cast to `any`. Feel free to include all other properties as well and type appropriately.

In case you need different values on the mocked properties you can simply spy on them and change the value using `returnValue` of jasmine:

```
const spy: any = spyOn((service as any)._window, 'location').and.returnValue({hash: 'AnotherHash'});
```

or

```
const spy: any = spyOn((service as any)._window.location, 'hash').and.returnValue('AnotherHash');
```