# How to get height and width of device display in angular2 using typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I found this solution. Is it valid?

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({...})
export MyApp {
constructor(platform: Platform) {
  platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
    console.log('Width: ' + platform.width());
    console.log('Height: ' + platform.height());
  });
 }
}
```

This solution is for ionic 2.
can i also used for angular 2?

Please suggest me the right way to do it.

Comment: To answer your question, no. This is not a valid way in Angular 2, since Ionic is not a part of Angular, but visa versa. You'll still able to get the clients height/width using 'window'

Comment: @JoeriShoeby:- yes now i am trying 

    width: window.innerWidth,

    height: window.innerHeight
But i am getting an error. [ts] Cannot find namespace 'window'.

Comment: This is because of your Typescript compiler not knowing about 'window'. You'll probably need to install the typings to make sure your compiler recognizes it.

Comment: @JoeriShoeby:- Right. but how to install it?

Comment: Do you have any typings already installed? If not, first install typings using 'sudo npm install -g typings'

Comment: Yes, typings are already installed

Answer (score 77, accepted):

I found the solution. The answer is very simple. write the below code in your constructor.

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input } from "@angular/core";
// Import this, and write at the top of your .ts file
import { HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-login",
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    // Declare height and width variables
    scrHeight:any;
    scrWidth:any;

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    getScreenSize(event?) {
          this.scrHeight = window.innerHeight;
          this.scrWidth = window.innerWidth;
          console.log(this.scrHeight, this.scrWidth);
    }

    // Constructor
    constructor() {
        this.getScreenSize();
    }


}
```

**====== Working Code (Another) ======**

```
export class Dashboard  {
 mobHeight: any;
 mobWidth: any;
     constructor(private router:Router, private http: Http){
        this.mobHeight = (window.screen.height) + "px";
        this.mobWidth = (window.screen.width) + "px";
          console.log(this.mobHeight);
          console.log(this.mobWidth)
     }
}
```

Comment: show, thanks , work with angular 12 and ionic 6

Comment: What is the type of the 'event?' parameter inside getScreenSize? In Angular 13, it doesn't compile unless I explicitely pass event?: any (or maybe it is because of some settings I have). Also, as it is not used inside the function, is it even required?

Answer (score 159):

For those who want to get height and width of device even when the display is **resized** (**dynamically & in real-time**):

- Step 1:

In that Component do: `import { HostListener } from "@angular/core";`

- Step 2:

In the component's class body write:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event?) {
   this.screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
   this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

- Step 3:

In the component's `constructor` call the `onResize` method to **initialize** the variables. Also, don't forget to declare them first.

```
constructor() {
  this.onResize();
}
```

**Complete code:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "app-login",
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class FooComponent implements OnInit {
    screenHeight: number;
    screenWidth: number;

    constructor() {
        this.getScreenSize();
    }

    @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
    getScreenSize(event?) {
          this.screenHeight = window.innerHeight;
          this.screenWidth = window.innerWidth;
          console.log(this.screenHeight, this.screenWidth);
    }

}
```

Comment: how about minimum height (min-height)?

Comment: screenHeight:any;
    screenWidth:any; they are numbers ;)

Comment: This explanation helped so much.  I was also able to switch the expand/collapse by testing for width breakpoint in the HostListener width change event.  Perfect!

Comment: @BlackBeard : why is that questionmark in function definition after event ? i.e. getScreenSize(event?) . I am unaware about it. is it a practice?

Comment: @omkar Angular2+ uses Typescript; In Typescript a questionmark (?) can be used in method signature like shown to mark optional parameters. In this example HostListener will provide event (I guess it has been provided just for sake of completeness - you dont need to forward in this example) and the initial call from constructor will not provide event. If you omit marking optionality while it is needed the typescript compiler in IDE or maybe ng-build later-on could throw warning / error about signature discrepancy.

Comment: Should change the function name to setScreenSize.

Comment: is it possible to get the device's status bar height? am trying to do a sticky navbar (already has `z-index` set, and `top` set based on some `viewport`). however, it's still acting funky and awkward

Answer (score 30):

```
export class Dashboard {
    innerHeight: any;
    innerWidth: any;
    constructor() {
        this.innerHeight = (window.screen.height) + "px";
        this.innerWidth = (window.screen.width) + "px";
    }
}
```

Comment: Window is not defined?

Answer (score 11):

You may use the typescript getter method for this scenario. Like this

```
public get height() {
  return window.innerHeight;
}

public get width() {
  return window.innerWidth;
}
```

And use that in template like this:

```
<section [ngClass]="{ 'desktop-view': width >= 768, 'mobile-view': width < 768 
}"></section>
```

Print the value

```
console.log(this.height, this.width);
```

You won't need any event handler to check for resizing of window, this method will check for size every time automatically.

Comment: I am using this method. But it is not working properly all the time. In loading the page it works fine. At first changing the size of the browser it works and suddenly it stops to detect changes. Do you have any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: Can't understand from this description, can you share code snippet?

Answer (score 7):

Keep in mind if you are wanting to test this component you will want to inject the window. Use the @Inject() function to inject the window object by naming it using a string token like detailed in this [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568913/unit-testing-mocking-window-properties-in-angular2-typescript)

Answer (score 0):

I've read that it's recommended that you Inject `DOCUMENT` in the constructor so it works on both rendering platforms: browser and server side. The global DOM reference to `window` only works for browser rendering platforms. To get access to the widow object you can use `DOCUMENT`:

`@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document`

```
console.log('window height ', this._document.defaultview.innerHeight);
console.log('window height ', this._document.defaultview.innerWidth);
```