# Detecting real time window size changes in Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, dom-events

I have been trying to build a responsive nav-bar and do not wish to use a media query, so I intend to use `*ngIf` with the window size as a criterion.
But I have been facing a problem as I am unable to find any method or documentation on Angular 4 window size detection. I have also tried the JavaScript method, but it is not supported.

I have also tried the [following](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_screen.asp):

```js
constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then((readySource) => {
        console.log('Width: ' + platform.width());
        console.log('Height: ' + platform.height());
    });
}
```

...which was used in ionic.

And `screen.availHeight`, but still no success.

Comment: What is `platform` about? Is this about Ionic?

Comment: @Günter Zöchbauer The Platform is angular, just wanted to mention the codes that i had tried.

Comment: [`Platform`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform) is an Ionic service. So i'm guessing it's an Ionic project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get height and width of device display in angular2 using typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39888768/how-to-get-height-and-width-of-device-display-in-angular2-using-typescript)

Comment: @BlackBeard I don't think it's a duplicate due to how much Angular 2 and 4 differ.

Comment: @tehlivi see the solution. They are same!

Comment: Good article for answering this question https://scotch.io/tutorials/detect-responsive-screen-sizes-in-angular

Answer (score 447, accepted):

To get it on init

```
public innerWidth: any;
ngOnInit() {
    this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

If you wanna keep it updated on resize:

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  this.innerWidth = window.innerWidth;
}
```

Comment: this.innerWidth = event.target.innerWidth; ... is possibly more efficient, produces the same result

Comment: Also recommend this in the constructor if you are using lodash ... this.onResize = debounce(this.onResize, 150, {leading: false, trailing: true}) ... to prevent the onResize method being called too frequently ... you will need to ... import { debounce } from 'lodash'

Comment: I think preferred to use `ngAfterViewInit` life hook method instead of  `ngOnInit`  life hook method

Comment: The @HostListener code can come within an angular component (e.g., under the constructor. The ['$event'] and event parameter can be skipped, although the innerWidth can also be found in that parameter, which would make the function more testable. To make the code more DRY, you can call onResize from within ngOnInit or ngAfterViewInit, but then you have to deal with the event parameter.

Comment: Hi, where to add the second code snippet?

Comment: I added this to my app.component and it worked fine (with lodash):

  @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  onResize(event) {
    doYourStuff();
    this.onResize = debounce(this.onResize, 150, {
      leading: false,
      trailing: true,
    });
  }

Answer (score 80):

If you want to react on certain breakpoints (e.g. do something if width is 768px or less), you can use [`BreakpointObserver`](https://material.angular.io/cdk/layout/api#BreakpointObserver):

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

  constructor(
    private breakpointObserver: BreakpointObserver,
  ) {
    // detect screen size changes
    this.breakpointObserver.observe([
      "(max-width: 768px)"
    ]).subscribe((result: BreakpointState) => {
      if (result.matches) {
          // hide stuff        
      } else {
          // show stuff
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: if you want to act only if the observer matches criteria you got to add inside subscribe this `if (result.matches)` otherwise it will call even if it don't

Comment: @karoluS: Yes of course. I edited my answer to make that clear. Thank you.

Comment: Seems that this `cdk` has peer dependency on specific version of angular. Like 7 for the latest. Anyway I can use this for older version(angular 4 as in the question)?

Comment: @Leon li: I actually use angular 7, that's right. However: As far as I know you can use cdk in angular 4 too. According to [this blog post](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/angular4/angular4_materials.htm) you need cdk 2.x. As far as I know, this has to be installed manually and with the version specified like this: npm @angular/cdk@4

Comment: @JeremyBenks Y, we are using ng `4.2.6` specifically. Cannot find a cdk 2.x verison on that, only 4.1.x and 4.3.x. Anyway, Thanks!

Comment: @Leon li: according to [npm (in versions)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cdk) there is a version 2.0.0-beta.12. But I found that this is not found with a normal npm install @angular/cdk@2, you have to specify the full version e.g. npm install @angular/cdk@2.0.0-beta.12. But you might not want to use a beta version.. Well, maybe update angular soon? ;-)

Answer (score 19):

This is an example of service which I use.

You can get the screen width by subscribing to `screenWidth$`, or via `screenWidth$.value`.

The same is for `mediaBreakpoint$` ( or `mediaBreakpoint$.value`)

```
import {
  Injectable,
  OnDestroy,
} from '@angular/core';
import {
  Subject,
  BehaviorSubject,
  fromEvent,
} from 'rxjs';
import {
  takeUntil,
  debounceTime,
} from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class ResponsiveService implements OnDestroy {
  private _unsubscriber$: Subject<any> = new Subject();
  public screenWidth$: BehaviorSubject<number> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
  public mediaBreakpoint$: BehaviorSubject<string> = new BehaviorSubject(null);

  constructor() {
    this.init();
  }

  init() {
    this._setScreenWidth(window.innerWidth);
    this._setMediaBreakpoint(window.innerWidth);
    fromEvent(window, 'resize')
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(1000),
        takeUntil(this._unsubscriber$)
      ).subscribe((evt: any) => {
        this._setScreenWidth(evt.target.innerWidth);
        this._setMediaBreakpoint(evt.target.innerWidth);
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this._unsubscriber$.next();
    this._unsubscriber$.complete();
  }

  private _setScreenWidth(width: number): void {
    this.screenWidth$.next(width);
  }

  private _setMediaBreakpoint(width: number): void {
    if (width < 576) {
      this.mediaBreakpoint$.next('xs');
    } else if (width >= 576 && width < 768) {
      this.mediaBreakpoint$.next('sm');
    } else if (width >= 768 && width < 992) {
      this.mediaBreakpoint$.next('md');
    } else if (width >= 992 && width < 1200) {
      this.mediaBreakpoint$.next('lg');
    } else if (width >= 1200 && width < 1600) {
      this.mediaBreakpoint$.next('xl');
    } else {
      this.mediaBreakpoint$.next('xxl');
    }
  }

}
```

Hope this helps someone

Comment: My favourite answer! Just make sure you add this.init() in the constructor for it to work.

Answer (score 14):

If you'd like you components to remain easily testable you should wrap the global window object in an Angular Service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()
export class WindowService {

  get windowRef() {
    return window;
  }

}
```

You can then inject it like any other service:

```
constructor(
    private windowService: WindowService
) { }
```

And consume...

```
  ngOnInit() {
      const width= this.windowService.windowRef.innerWidth;
  }
```

Comment: I can't see the point on doing a service to do exactly what it's already at hand.
window.innerWidth.

Comment: Firstly DI is the Angular way and makes the dependencies of a component / directive clearer. But the main point mentioned here is to make the code that uses the service easier to test. Using this approach the WindowService can be mocked in any test written for components that use the service.

Answer (score 11):

The documentation for `Platform` [`width()`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#width) and [`height()`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/platform/Platform/#height), it's stated that these methods use `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight` respectively. But using the methods are preferred since the dimensions are cached values, which reduces the chance of multiple and expensive DOM reads.

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

...
private width:number;
private height:number;

constructor(private platform: Platform){
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.width = platform.width();
        this.height = platform.height();
    });
}
```

Comment: How does getting `width` of `window` relate to `DOM` ? 
Logically, it should not depend on what dom tree looks like.

Answer (score 9):

***The answer is very simple. write the below code***

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, Input } from "@angular/core";
// Import this, and write at the top of your .ts file
import { HostListener } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
 selector: "app-login",
 templateUrl: './login.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
// Declare height and width variables
scrHeight:any;
scrWidth:any;

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
getScreenSize(event?) {
      this.scrHeight = window.innerHeight;
      this.scrWidth = window.innerWidth;
      console.log(this.scrHeight, this.scrWidth);
}

// Constructor
constructor() {
    this.getScreenSize();
}
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You may use the typescript getter method for this scenario. Like this

```
public get width() {
  return window.innerWidth;
}
```

And use that in template like this:

```
<section [ngClass]="{ 'desktop-view': width >= 768, 'mobile-view': width < 768 
}"></section>
```

You won't need any event handler to check for resizing/ of window, this method will check for size every time automatically.

Answer (score 7):

Now i know that the question is originally referring to the **Screen size** so basically the `width` and `height` attributes, but for most people **`Breakpoints` are what really matter**, therefore, and to make a global reusable solution, I would prefer using `Angular`'s `BreakpointObserver` to handle this.

The following configuration is basically a `service` with some `functions` that can `return` an `Observable<BreakpointState>` and to be `subscribed` wherever needed:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { BreakpointObserver, BreakpointState } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export class ScreenService {

  constructor(private observer: BreakpointObserver) {}

  isBelowSm(): Observable<BreakpointState> {
    return this.observer.observe(['(max-width: 575px)']);
  }

  isBelowMd(): Observable<BreakpointState> {
    return this.observer.observe(['(max-width: 767px)']);
  }

  isBelowLg(): Observable<BreakpointState> {
    return this.observer.observe(['(max-width: 991px)']);
  }

  isBelowXl(): Observable<BreakpointState> {
    return this.observer.observe(['(max-width: 1199px)']);
  }
}
```

The above code can be adjusted to deal with screen size the `bootstrap` way (*By changing `max-width` into `min-width` and adding `1px` for each value, and ofcourse to inverse `function`s names.*)

Now in the `component class`, simply `subscribing` to the `observable` returned by any of the above functions would do.

*i.e: `app.component.ts`*:

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  isBelowLg: boolean;

  constructor(private screenService: ScreenService) {}

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.screenService.isBelowLg().subscribe((isBelowLg: BreakpointState) => {
      this.isBelowLg = isBelowLg.matches;
    });
  }
}
```

Refer that using `AfterViewInit` life cycle hook would save lot of trouble for when it comes to `detectChanges()` after view was initialized.

## EDIT:

As an alternative for `AfterViewInit` it's the same, but additionally, you will need to use `ChangeDetectorRef` to `detectChanges()`, simply inject an instance in the subscribing component *i.e: `app.component.ts`* like this:

```
constructor(
    private screenService: ScreenService,
    private cdref: ChangeDetectorRef
  ) {}
```

And afterwards, just a call for `detectChanges()` would do:

```
this.cdref.detectChanges();
```

Answer (score 6):

```
@HostListener("window:resize", [])
public onResize() {
  this.detectScreenSize();
}

public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.detectScreenSize();
}

private detectScreenSize() {
    const height = window.innerHeight;
    const width = window.innerWidth;
}
```

Comment: Always explain why this might be the right solution

Answer (score 5):

you can use this 
https://github.com/ManuCutillas/ng2-responsive 
Hope it helps :-)