# how to change mat-stroked-button to mat-button in typescript class?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a material button mat-stroked-button as the following:

```
<button mat-stroked-button color="accent" class="mat-login-header">Login</button>
```

I need if the user uses a smaller screen size or resolution (such as mobile screen) the button changes its type to mat-button, so in the component constructor I am trying:

```
constructor() {
  if(document.body.clientWidth < 600) {
    //how to change the button from mat-stroked-button to mat-button?
  }
}
```

So how can I change it to mat-button if document width is less than 600 and otherwise keep it mat-stroked-button

Comment: what about creating two blocks of buttons and change which one is visible with a *ngIf based on a variable, smallUI for example?

Comment: My first guess was to do `[attr.mat-stroked-button]="condition"` unfortunately it does not seem to work. So I suggest you to use @hamilton.lima 's solution.

Comment: @Ploppy That's because the `mat-stroked-button` is declared as a directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A straightforward way to do it would be create a variable (e.g., `useStroked`) and then use `*ngIf` with the two different Material button components:

```
<button *ngIf="useStroked" mat-stroked-button color="accent" class="mat-login-header">Login</button>
<button *ngIf="!useStroked" mat-button color="accent" class="mat-login-header">Login</button>
```

You will then need to set that variable in your TS class (for an example see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45350792/4530745)).

I created a sample StackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-v5utqj?file=app%2Fbutton-types-example.ts).

Answer (score 0):

Right now. Using two buttons with `*ngIf` is obsolete. You can use the class to style your buttons instead of the directive. With that said, the following line works.

```
<button mat-button [ngClass]={"mat-stroked-button": isScreenSmall} color="accent" class="mat-login-header">Login</button>
```

`isScreenSmall` is a boolean variable that indicates if the screen size is mobile.

Comment: `mat-stroked-button` isn't a class, it's an attribute so unfortunatley this method doesn't work