# How to set different css class based on screen size in Angular?

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ng-class

I have this floating button in my Angular Application,

```
  <button [ngClass]="{
  'mdc-fab--extended': extendedClass,
  'mdc-fab--mini': miniClass
}" class="mdc-fab mdc-fab--touch    ">
<div class="mdc-fab__ripple"></div>
<span class="material-icons mdc-fab__icon">mail</span>
<!-- <span class="floating-span">My Invite Link</span> -->
<div class="mdc-fab__touch"></div>
```

And I need to change the mdc-fab--extended className to mdc-fab--mini when screen size is 768px or lower?
What can I do to achieve this functionality?
Thanks

I've tried this but the classes are not being removed/added

```
    if (window.innerWidth < 768) {
  this.miniClass = true;
  this.extendedClass = false;
} else {
  this.miniClass = false;
  this.extendedClass = true;
}
```

Comment: you taking about resizing window ??

Comment: The expression in your template is not written properly. I am adding it to the answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can add `hostlistener` to your component.

```
public size700_1020 = false;
public size400_700 = false;

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
   alert(window.screen.availWidth);
   alert(window.screen.availHeight);

   if(window.innerWidth < 700 && window.innerHeight < 1020) {
       // now based on the screen size you want to check 
       // enable the variable and make it true
       // based on it, you can enable the class in template
   } 
}
```

In template:

```
<div class="size700_1020 ? 'addThisClass' : 'elseThis'"></div>
```

There are multiple properties for your requirement on `window` object. I am attaching some links which might give you more ways [here1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3437786/get-the-size-of-the-screen-current-web-page-and-browser-window) and [here2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45350716/detecting-real-time-window-size-changes-in-angular-4).

You can also do this.

```
import { Platform } from 'ionic-angular';

...
private width:number;
private height:number;

constructor(private platform: Platform){
    platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.width = platform.width();
        this.height = platform.height();
    });
}
```

As per the changes made in the question:

```
  <button [ngClass]="miniClass ? 'addMiniClass':'extendedClass'" class="mdc-fab mdc-fab--touch    ">
<div class="mdc-fab__ripple"></div>
<span class="material-icons mdc-fab__icon">mail</span>
<!-- <span class="floating-span">My Invite Link</span> -->
<div class="mdc-fab__touch"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

> Component.ts

```
    classFlag = false;
    ngOnInit(){
     if (screen.width <= 768) {
      this.classFlag = true;
    } else {
      this.classFlag = false;
    } 
  }
```

> HTML

```
<button class="mdc-fab  mdc-fab--touch"
  [ngClass]="classFlag ? 'mdc-fab--extended' : 'mdc-fab--mini'">
</button>
```

try `screen.width` instead of `window.innerWidth`

Answer (score 0):

Component :

```
classFlag = false;
ngOnInit(){
  if (window.innerWidth <= 768) {
    this.classFlag = true;
  } else {
    this.classFlag = false;
  } 
 }
```

HTML :

```
<button class="mdc-fab  mdc-fab--touch"
  [ngClass]="classFlag ? 'mdc-fab--extended' : 'mdc-fab--mini'">
</button>
```

Triggering on RESIZING WINDOW OR BROWSER
Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/49917082/11492378

Comment: I've tried this but the mdc-fab--mini class does not get applied when width is <= 768, 

i switched your classes in your ngClass since thats the logic I applied but still i dont understand why its not changing?

Comment: are you checking it by resizing your browser ?

Comment: yes i have inspector open and and browser is 768px width or less its still same mdc-fab--extended class and not mdc-fab--mini class

Comment: You need to append the hostlistener and based on that you can add the classes. Please check my answer if that makes any sense.

Comment: no then you need to use `HostListener` for event. like @Apoova answer

Comment: ahh I see the HostListener works now!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49917082/11492378

Reff -