# How to get the host in angular2

Tags: angular

I'm looking for a way to get the host of the current URL using Angular2.
So on

```
 http://example.com/myapp.html
```

I want to get:

```
 example.com
```

(in angular1 I used $location.host() to parse it out. Is there something similar?)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get domain name for service in Angular2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36222845/how-to-get-domain-name-for-service-in-angular2)

Answer (score 9):

Well, there's the old fashioned window.location JavaScript object.
It has all of the elements that compose a url under it.
Try printing it to the console to take a look:

console.log(window.location);

Edit:

What you actually need is
window.location.host

See: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_location.asp

Comment: Accessing the window object is not recommended. Use [Location](https://v4.angular.io/api/common/Location) class.

Answer (score 1):

window.location.*** it is as mentioned above.
Here's the visual representation of different location properties:
http://bl.ocks.org/abernier/3070589

Answer (score 1):

`location.hostname`
For example, in your ts file, let x = `//${location.hostname}`
and in your browser you type: http://www.example.com
you get x="http://www.example.com"
then you get example from x should be easy.